# How to continue to next line of code, if variable calculated is not an integer

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators, modulus

** UPDATE: This was solved, by Loc Tran! Thank you LocTran!! **

I am writing a program, (using strictly C) which calculates the minimum change in US denominations. After my program reaches dimes (the first denomination that is not divisible by a whole number the program seems to not want to continue to nickels and pennies.

I have tried to use an if statement, excluding dimesDue value if returning a zero, but cant seem to figure it out. If you notice, I also had to make a new change variable for each denomination, based on the previous denominations deduction from the total change amount. I would prefer to simplify this and specify the new value after each calculation, but could not.

```
// Amount Tendered and Purchase amount converted to pennies

amountDue = 2117;
amountGiven = 10000;

// Creating a new change amount for each denomination, based on each previous computation

change = amountGiven - amountDue;
change10s = change % (20 * 100);
change5s = change % (10 * 100);
change1s = change % (5 * 100);
changeQs = change % (1 * 100);
changeDs = change % 25; 
changeNs = change % 10;
changePs = change % 1;

// Using each new change amount to calculate amount of denomination 

twentiesDue = (change / 20) / 100;
tensDue = (change10s / 10) / 100;
fivesDue = (change5s / 5) / 100;
onesDue = (change1s / 1) / 100;
quartersDue = (changeQs / 25);
dimesDue = (changeDs / 10);
nickelsDue = (changeNs / 5);
penniesDue = (changePs / 1);

printf("Amount Due: $21.17\nAmount Tendered: $100\n\n");
printf("Change Due:\n(by denomination)\n");
printf("Twenties: %d\n", twentiesDue);
printf("Tens: %d\n", tensDue);
printf("Fives: %d\n", fivesDue);
printf("Ones: %d\n", onesDue);
printf("Quarters: %d\n", quartersDue);
printf("Dimes: %d\n", dimesDue);
printf("Nickels: %d\n", nickelsDue);
printf("Pennies: %d\n", penniesDue);
```

The program reaches dimes (the first denomination that does not equal a whole number) and does not continue on to caculate the amount of nickels and pennies. Because the remainder of change left after quarters is 8 cents, this is not divisible by 10. but I cant figure out how to specify to ignore this using a if statement!

So the result is once the program reaches dimes, all variable thereafter compute to zero. But there should be one nickel and three pennies!
Here is the result when I run it:

Amount Due: $21.17
Amount Tendered: $100

Change Due:
(by denomination)
Twenties: 3
Tens: 1
Fives: 1
Ones: 3
Quarters: 3
Dimes: 0
Nickels: 0
Pennies: 0

Comment: this is a classic case of needing to debug your program stepping through line by line and it will soon be obvious

Comment: An issue to think about: suppose `change == 25`.  Then `(change % 100) / 25` is 1, and `(change % 10) / 5` is 1, so you're going to give 25 cents in the form of one quarter and one nickel.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys. Hmmm, okay. I am going through line by line, and am starting to think the issue lies somewhere in here: (is the fact that dimes don’t divide into an integer creating a problem?) if So, is an if statement required in here? 
change = amountGiven - amountDue;
change10s = change % (20 * 100);
change5s = change % (10 * 100);
change1s = change % (5 * 100);
changeQs = change % (1 * 100);
changeDs = change % 25; 
changeNs = change % 10;
changePs = change % 1;

Comment: Possible for each of these variables? Just by chance dimes are the only non whole number divisible variable in this program. But I bet If the change was 17 cents then the issue would begin with quarters. I’m at a loss)

Comment: So take a step back from the code you've written. How would you work out the correct answer without a computer, just in your head or on paper? What steps did you take to do that? If you can formalize those steps well enough to get a correct algorithm, then you can think about useful shortcuts, as long as you're sure they give the same results in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Although this solution works, I can't use it.
Modulus operator MUST be used.***

You have a problem with calculating the remaining amount after changing with a monetary value. It is similar procedure to get all digits in a number. For example, with 198 after get 1, the remaining is 198-1*100 = 98, then we get 9 , the remaining is 98-9*10=8, and get 8 then we done.
You calculated with a wrong formula. Here is my calculation with the same manner of getting digits in a number, and the entire solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
// Amount Tendered and Purchase amount converted to pennies
int amountDue = 2117;
int amountGiven = 10000;

// Using each new change amount to calculate amount of denomination

// getting 20dollars notes
int change = amountGiven - amountDue;
int twentiesDue = (change / 20) / 100;

// get the remaining after change 20dollar notes, and 
// then divide 10*100 for getting 10dollars notes
int change10s = change % (20*100);
int tensDue = (change10s / 10) / 100;

// get the remaining after change 10dollar notes, and 
// then divide 5*100 for getting 5dollars notes
int change5s = change10s % (10*100);
int fivesDue = (change5s / 5) / 100;

// get the remaining after change 5dollar notes, and 
// then divide 1*100 for getting 1dollars notes
int change1s = change5s % (5*100);
int onesDue = (change1s / 1) / 100;

// get the remaining after change 1dollar notes, and 
// then divide 25 for getting quarter coins
int changeQs = change1s % (1*100);
int quartersDue = (changeQs / 25);

// get the remaining after change quarter coins, and 
// then divide 10 for getting dime coins
int changeDs = changeQs % 25;
int dimesDue = (changeDs / 10);

// get the remaining after change dime coins, and 
// then divide 5 for getting nickel coins
int changeNs = changeDs % 10;
int nickelsDue = (changeNs / 5);

// get the remaining after change nickel coins, and 
// then divide 1 for getting 1cent coins
int changePs = changeNs % 5;
int penniesDue = (changePs / 1);

printf("Amount Due: $21.17\nAmount Tendered: $100\n\n");
printf("Change Due:\n(by denomination)\n");
printf("Twenties: %d\n", twentiesDue);
printf("Tens: %d\n", tensDue);
printf("Fives: %d\n", fivesDue);
printf("Ones: %d\n", onesDue);
printf("Quarters: %d\n", quartersDue);
printf("Dimes: %d\n", dimesDue);
printf("Nickels: %d\n", nickelsDue);
printf("Pennies: %d\n", penniesDue);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a to the point answer. And I really appreciate you helping explain a solution off the code I posted, rather than typing your own in and expecting me to understand it. I ran your through and it works perfectly, I compared them line by line and see what I was doing wrong. Each new denomination/change value was specified in an inefficient way. Thank you!

Comment: I just realized, although Loc Tran's help was graciously appreciated, I must use the modulus for this program. So I cannot find the change using subtraction . Loc Tran, any ideas?

Comment: @Jedi_Sk8Tricks I'm done for your suggestion. Please update.

Comment: Thank you, wow you are good. I'm dissecting the original code now, and seeing how the modulus was used in your method vs my original method. Are you on LinkedIn

Comment: @Jedi_Sk8Tricks, yeah.

Comment: @Jedi_Sk8Tricks yeah, there are some different stuff between them

Comment: ,Thanks again for the help and your time, I would feel bad to take up any more of it!

Comment: @Jedi_Sk8Tricks Please review and accept if it solve your problem. Thank you